# matplotlib._png just broke in Anaconda Windows 5.0.0, python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
```

Error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in <module>()
     26 # For clarity, names from _image are given explicitly in this module:
     27 import matplotlib._image as _image
---> 28 import matplotlib._png as _png
     29 
     30 # For user convenience, the names from _image are also imported into

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Any ideas how to fix? A coworker and I both ran into this yesterday so I know it's not just me.

Comment: Usually such errors come from a discrepancy between the matplotlib version and some other dependency. E.g. if you install a binary wheel for 64bit system on python 32bit or so. Maybe you can check if you ran into such a situation here.

Comment: Try `> conda update matplotlib` ?

Comment: Thanks -- didn't help though. Turns out it was an install of CNTK 2.3.1 that was trashing zlib.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit for me was upgrading CNTK from 2.3 to 2.3.1. Apparently it's a known issue. Description/fix here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2423